# How to hide printing list in OpenERP?

Tags: printing, report, odoo

It's possible to hide this report menu when in the "draft" state?

[image]

Someone please give me some advide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually a toolbar which is independent of the record list's state. So its not possible